# make is unable to compile Vc library

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, cmake, compilation, gnu-make

I am trying to compile the master branch of [Vc](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc) on my system but `make` is not working and not giving any erorrs.
`cmake` ran fine with the only missing things being `Intel SDE not found` and `MIC SDK was not found!`.

if I run:

```
$ ls
cmake  CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  CTestCustom.cmake  Makefile
$ make
$
```

I can see the makefile in the directory but the prompt just returns empty and no action is performed by make. Is the Makefile broken?

Comment: Looks like some functionality of the project is disabled - [CMakeLists.txt:225](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L225): `if(FALSE) # disabled for now`.

Comment: You're right. I had to `checkout` a different branch to get that library working. Do you mind sharing how you spotted that detail? Did you clone thesame repo and try to run `make` as well?

Comment: I just searched `add_library`/`add_executable` calls in the `CMakeLists.txt`, and found that such call is protected by `if(FALSE)` guard.